# System architect courses for mainframes

Tags: architecture, environment, mainframe, regions

I am working on main frames.
I am trying to understand the existing system architecture in my project. I am facing difficulty in understanding test environment and regions and development environment and regions. I want to know what exactly an environment or region mean and how to setup one

Do you know any tutorials regarding setting up / understanding mainframe architecture.
TIA...

Any other suggestions are invited

Comment: This is not a 'mainframe architecture' questions. These terms are applicable to any professional IT platform. Unless these 'regions' you mention are CICS regions...

Comment: google "master the mainframe" it's a free contest IBM provides every year.

Answer (score 0):

This would be specific to your site.

Most places have multiple environments EX:

- Production
- Unit Test

A Region (as SteveIves says in the comments) usually refers to a CICS region.

You will need to ask someone at your site what these terms actually mean for you. You could potentially have many enviroments and each environment could have many regions (if we are correct about the regions being CICS regions).

Depending on what environment(s) or region(s) you need to set up/learn about, the answer could be different. Talk to someone more senior at your site and ask them. Without working at your site, we can only guess at the correct answer.